# How do you use a PS4 Controller for the desktop environment?

Tags: gnome, gui, input-devices, gamepad

I am using a PS4 controller on steam and it works a charm. How can I use it to control the GNOME desktop environment?

Answer (score 0):

I did it years ago using xpadder, but I think it is just for Windows. You could try [qjoypad](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/qjoypad) [image: Install qjoypad] or [joy2key](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/joy2key) [image: Install joy2key]. Both of these are available in the Software Center.